# Should I install amd64-microcode?

Tags: 13.04, ati, cpu, ubuntu-tweak, amd-processor

This is my system:

```
AMD Phenom II x4 960T (unlocked to 6 cores)
8GB 1066 DDR2 RAM
Gigabyte Radeon HD6670 1GB DDR3 (AMD Catalyst 13.4 propriety driver)
Ubuntu 13.04 at 1920x1080 60Hz
Dual boot with Win7 64-bit
Logitech H390 USB headset
```

I am playing Left 4 Dead 2 beta, Portal beta, Trine 2, and other steam games.  According to [this google site](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed#TOC-Install-the-latest-microcode-for-your-processor-CPU-), installing [amd64-microcode](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/amd64-microcode) could speed up my system.  When I clicked to install using the software center, Ubuntu wanted to remove `linux-firmware`, `linux-generic`, and `linux-image-generic`.

Does anyone know the benefits and/or risks to doing this?

Comment: just so you know this program is 32-bit only, it might not speed up your computer if you are running a 64-bit operating system. It will not crash because of that but the effect may be less.

Comment: So I'm getting the idea this won't do much.  Is that what you are saying, Alvar?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point of doing this since the program is in 32-bit and your system is in 64-bit, the speed you may gain is lost in that it's a 32-bit program. 
I don't think this program is designed for your hardware, it's probably intended for a 32-bit CPU and a 32-bit operating system.